# Why Jira and Confluence data center admin automatically logout after refresh pages?

Tags: jira, confluence

Using HAProxy as a load balancer.

From the official guide set the configuration:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/enterprise/jira-data-center-load-balancer-examples-781200827.html

Here is the configuration for HAProxy:

```
frontend jira
    bind :::8080 v4v6
    default_backend             jira

frontend confluence
    bind :::8090 v4v6
    default_backend             confluence

backend jira
    balance     roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
    server jira1 [IP1]:8080 check cookie jira1
    server jira2 [IP2]:8080 check cookie jira2

backend confluence
    balance     roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
    server confluence1 [IP3]:8090 check cookie confluence1
    server confluence2 [IP4]:8090 check cookie confluence2
```

It works when login into the system. But after refresh page sometime, it will been logout automatically.

And, I didn't find cookie in browser after login into the system as screenshot attached.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and then i came across the link below, it turns out that both applications are using the same cookie name which is causing an overwrite on every log in.

When user log in to Jira a value gets stored with JSESSIONID name. and then user logs in to Confluence which also stores the cookie value on JSESSIONID which causes an overwrite to the Jira cookie name. If user goes back to Jira and refreshes, they will be redirected to the log in page since the cookie was not recognized ( Jira original cookie is gone )

[Logging into another Atlassian application logs me out of Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/logging-into-another-atlassian-application-logs-me-out-of-confluence-268043930.html)

The case presented in the thread above is for Jira and Confluence Server.

I believe you should also update the HA proxy configuration sessionCookieName for confluence to something else other than JSESSIONID .